# how to use firebase firestore "where! ="

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do something like this in the firestore

```
      const sendwant = (f) => {
    fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("Rooms")
      .doc(f.roomname)
      .collection("wants")
      .doc()
      .where("user","!=",f.displayName)
      .set({
        user: user.displayName,
        status: false,
        roomname: f.roomname,
        created: f.user,
        date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("You sent a request to join this room wait for an answer");
      });
  };
```

Since I don't want multiple same users in the collection, I want this operation to run when the user value is not equal to the displayName value. If you know another way please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **never** will give any results:

```
  .collection("wants")
  .doc()
  .where("user","!=",f.displayName)
```

The `doc()` call in here creates a reference to a new, non-existing, unique document. And you when filter that for only documents with a specific condition.

If you want all documents from `wants` with a different display name, that'd be:

```
  .collection("wants")
  .where("user","!=",f.displayName)
```